# Magento url rewrite issues - all pages without www redirect to homepage

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess, canonical

Every page without w w w redirects to the homepage. Pages work normally with the w w w & the homepage redirects from non w w w to w w w.

(I want w w w only on the website)

I have tried changing configuration / web /auto redirect to base url but this just makes all of the pages accessible with w w w or without so causes duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to htaccess fixed the exact same problem for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```